# Representation theory of $S_k \wr S_n\subset S_{kn}$

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

I would like to know of a reference with a detailed treatment of the relation between irreducible representations of the permutation group $S_{kn}$ and those of the subgroup given by the wreath product $S_k \wr S_n$.

For instance, is it known what is the multiplicity of the trivial representation of the subgroup in each irrep of the group? If theory cannot provide these quantities in general, are there available tables?

Comment: The word to google is "plethysm".  These multiplicities are notoriously not well understood, even for the trivial representation.

Comment: @Nate thanks, I can google that word, but I would prefer something specific to these groups, instead of generalities

Comment: When people say plethysm coefficients they usually mean exactly these multiplicities (although there are other equivalent definitions). For a reference I think the appendix of Stanley's EC2 explains this for wreath products.

Comment: @Nate Ah, ok, sorry, I was put off track by the Wikipedia page on plethysm...

Comment: These are the same multiplicities as those mentioned on the wikipedia page, they are related by Schur-Weyl duality. But yea, take a look at EC2.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04018